# Why comparing indicators values aren't working with operators in Pine Script

Tags: pine-script

I wrote the code below:

```py
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © AliBahaari

//@version=4
study("RMI")

rsiInd = rsi(close, 14)
mfiInd = mfi(close, 14)

dangerZone = (rsiInd >= 70) and (mfiInd >= 70)
safeZone = (rsiInd <= 30) and (mfiInd <= 30)

plot(dangerZone ? 1 : 0, color=color.red, style=plot.style_columns)
plot(safeZone ? -1 : 0, color=color.green, style=plot.style_columns)
```

Sometimes RSI is under 30 and MFI doesn't but it shows on my oscillator. Why?

[image]

In the image above, you see MFI isn't under 30 but my script worked.

Comment: I compiled your script and it's working well, when rsi si bellow 30 and mfi bellow 30, plot -1, else plot 0. Maybe you should add an image with the chart to see the issue.

Comment: It works. I don't see where you are plotting the horizontal line in your code. Maybe that is the issue. Send complete code.